# Databricks Streaming Jobs Mysteriously Terminating after 5 minutes

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm trying to use Databricks on Azure with a Spark structured streaming job and an having very mysterious issue.

I boiled the job down it it's basics for testing, reading from a Kafka topic and writing to console in a forEachBatch.

On local, everything works fine indefinitely.

On Databricks, the task terminates after just over 5 minutes with a "Cancelled" status.

There are no errors in the log, just this, which appears to be a graceful shutdown request of some kind, but I don't know where it's coming from

```
22/11/04 18:31:30 INFO DriverCorral$: Cleaning the wrapper ReplId-1ea30-8e4c0-48422-a (currently in status Running(ReplId-1ea30-8e4c0-48422-a,ExecutionId(job-774316032912321-run-84401-action-5645198327600153),RunnableCommandId(9102993760433650959)))
22/11/04 18:31:30 INFO DAGScheduler: Asked to cancel job group 2207618020913201706_9102993760433650959_job-774316032912321-run-84401-action-5645198327600153
22/11/04 18:31:30 INFO ScalaDriverLocal: cancelled jobGroup:2207618020913201706_9102993760433650959_job-774316032912321-run-84401-action-5645198327600153 
22/11/04 18:31:30 INFO ScalaDriverWrapper: Stopping streams for commandId pattern: CommandIdPattern(2207618020913201706,None,Some(job-774316032912321-run-84401-action-5645198327600153)).
22/11/04 18:31:30 INFO DatabricksStreamingQueryListener: Stopping the stream [id=d41eff2a-4de6-4f17-8d1c-659d1c1b8d98, runId=5bae9fb4-b5e1-45a0-af1e-a2f2553592c9]
22/11/04 18:31:30 INFO DAGScheduler: Asked to cancel job group 5bae9fb4-b5e1-45a0-af1e-a2f2553592c9
22/11/04 18:31:30 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Cancelling stage 366
22/11/04 18:31:30 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Killing all running tasks in stage 366: Stage cancelled
22/11/04 18:31:30 INFO MicroBatchExecution: QueryExecutionThread.interruptAndAwaitExecutionThreadTermination called with streaming query exit timeout=15000 ms
```

For reference, here are is the code:

```
val incomingStream = spark.readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("subscribe",ehName)
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers",topicUriWithPort)
  .option("kafka.sasl.mechanism","PLAIN")
  .option("kafka.security.protocol","SASL_SSL")
  .option("kafka.sasl.jaas.config",jaas)
  .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") 
  .option("failOnDataLoss","false")
  .option("maxOffsetsPerTrigger", 1) //todo make config
  .load()

val processedWriteStream = incomingStream
  .writeStream
  .queryName("query2")
  .foreachBatch((d: DataFrame, b: Long) => {
    d.show()
  })
  .start()
processedWriteStream.awaitTermination()
```

Answer (score 1):

Structured Streaming provides fault-tolerance and data consistency for streaming queries; using Databricks [workflows](https://docs.databricks.com/structured-streaming/query-recovery.html), you can easily configure your Structured Streaming queries to restart on failure automatically.

You can restart the query after a failure by enabling checkpointing for a streaming query.

The restarted query continues where the failed one left off.